# Prawn-gmagick conflit with RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, prawn

I'm using the `rmagick` and `prawn-gmagick` gems. When I run `rails server`, I get the following error:

> Exiting
>       /home/macon10/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/polyglot-
>       0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require': This installation of RMagick was 
>       configured with ImageMagick 6.7.7 but GraphicsMagick 1.3.18 is in use. 
>       (RuntimeError)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't absolutely have to use rmagick, you can use [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) instead.